# login with post request. View iframe

Tags: php, post, iframe

I want to login with post request to external site. (another site is displayed in the iframe)

```
$url_1 = 'http://..............t.ru';
$ch = curl_init($url_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "X-HTTP-Method-Override" => "POST",
    "Cache-Control" => "no-cache"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "my_id=511;my_name=name;my_fullName=fname;my_authid=501");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "my_id=511&my_name=name&my_fullName=fname&my_authid =501");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have two sites, the second site is seen in the first site's iframe, I need to send information (cookie values) from the first site, so that the log-in process takes place automatically in the second one. The problem is, I don't know where I shoud send cookie values and how.

Comment: "but in the iframe isn't logs"...what does this mean? What did you expect, and what actually happened? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: A curl request is not the same as adding an iframe, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have two sites, the second site is seen in the first site's iframe,  I need to send information (cookie values) from the first site, so that the log-in process takes place automatically in the second one. The problem is, I don't know where I shoud send cookie values and how.